# Text field attribute make FROM To format in advanced search magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I have create a text field attribute( with Attribute Code "test") . It is showing on front end in advanced search. But i want to show it in format like weight or price. So that i will able to search record between 10 and 20(10-20).

and url should be like this when i click on search: catalogsearch/advanced/result/?weight[from]=5&weight[to]=10&manufacturer=&test[from]=10&test[to]=20

Please help how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

On your attribute from backend, you have to set the decimal backend type like the attribute "weight". It will show ranges automatically.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.

I am not getting about "decimal backend type". I am not seeing the field where i can set decimal backend type in my attribute.
I have also match same as "weight" attribute.
Please advise, from where i can set "decimal backend type" in my "test" attribute.

Please help.

Comment: Look at Backend / Catalog / Attributes / Manages Attributes. Click on your attribute, and you will find the field : "Input Validation for Store Owner"

Comment: Ok, i have select "Decimal Number" in Input Validation for Store Owner field. But still it is showing as textbox and when i click on search button, its url like 
catalogsearch/advanced/result/?weight[from]=&weight[to]=&manufacturer=4&test=
Actually i want url like catalogsearch/advanced/result/?weight[from]=&weight[to]=&manufacturer=4&test[from]=&test[to]= , and search show two boxes, one for "From" and other for "To".

Please help!

Comment: Sorry, I do a mistake. I just checked. Look at your attribute in the table "eav_attribute" from database. Change backend_type to "decimal" and frontend_input to "text". It will show ranges. Then reindex, flush cache, set yours values in yours products. It work for me.